# How to override dotnet publish's web.config?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

When I perform  `dotnet publish -c Release` then this `web.config` file is being added to my publish folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\aaa.xxxx.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

But I have different configuration on the server and I'd want to override it with my own config but, I have no idea how to do it.

I tried creating `web.config` file and setting it to `Copy always`.

But I receive:

> error MSB4018: The "TransformWebConfig" task failed unexpectedly.

> error MSB4018: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\web.config

Even when I run `dotnet publish -c Release` as admin.

Comment: Hmm..it works for me (VS2019). I read somewhere that it fails if *web.config* is read-only. Mind you check if yours is?

Comment: Probably that was the reason, ehh I hate this TFVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, the workaround that I use is:

```
rmdir bin /s /q
rmdir obj /s /q
rmdir output /s /q
dotnet publish -c Release -o output
del /f "output\web.config"
xcopy "prod_web.config" "output\web.config*"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

According to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/web-config?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Add the following to the approprate project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>true</IsTransformWebConfigDisabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```